# Fetch tables size in CData connectors

Tags: scala, cdata, cdata-drivers

I just want to fetch the size of tables provided by CData connectors like "Salesforce,MongoDb,etc".
So if anyone can help me in this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: As i didn't found anything regarding that, but as CData provides features to fetch column details, tables name, etc.But i also want to know the size of each table\